# OpenGL ES Matrix/Vector-Transform different than on desktiop OpenGL

Tags: android, c++, opengl-es

I've been porting a project of mine to Android lately, using GLES3 and the NDK.
Everything has been working well so far and I have come to a point where I should see my scene rendered completely the same as the desktop-application.

However, that is not the case. I was greeted with a blank (clear-color) screen at first and suspected the uniform-blocks not getting set correctly, which currently only contains a ViewProj-Matrix.

Now the strange stuff started to happen: I threw out the matrix transform of the vertex shader and I saw geometry drawn for the first time. So that data is okay at least (Also verified in Adreno Profiler). Must be the uniform-block, right?

Wrong! I hardcoded some colors as 4 vec4 into the uniform-block and verified them by outputting them. All were correct.

The only thing that doesn't work is to transform my vertices by the matrix. I've been transposing and trying different sides for multiplication. Although, I haven't found any source that stated there was a difference in ordering between usual OpenGL and GLES.

The problematic vertex-shader is the following:

```
#version 300 es
layout (std140) uniform buffer0
{  
    mat4 PF_ViewProj; 
};  

in vec3 vp;
in vec3 vnorm;
in vec2 vuv;
in vec4 vcolor;
in mat4 instanceWorld;
out vec3 f_nrm;
out vec2 f_uv;
out vec4 f_color;
void main () {
    gl_Position = PF_ViewProj * vec4(vp, 1.0);
    f_nrm = vnorm;
    f_uv = vuv;
    f_color = vcolor;
};
```

The desktop-version uses the same shader, only with a different #version-tag. The matrices also work fine in Direct3D11, although with different shader-code of course.

There shouldn't be any other differences in the OpenGL4 and GLES3 implementations of the engine, other than initialization.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Turned out you need to specify the layout-locations and I also used a corrupt projection-matrix, since the resolution of the EGL-Surface wasn't properly stored.